# volatile Thread not equal to the Thread.currentThread

Tags: java

I am learning about Threads in Java and I have the below program.  The while threadA condition check in ThreadA doesn't seem to be true as often as I would expect it.  The only println statement's I see in my console window contain the i variable greater than 100.  It seems as though its waiting and slowly printing out to the console.  I would image this would just be done in a second or so.  I've obviously misunderstood something here, any ideas on why the ThreadTester doesn't print out 100 times?

```
public class ThreadTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ThreadA threadA = new ThreadA();
        threadA.start();
    }
}

public class ThreadA extends Thread{
    private volatile Thread threadA = Thread.currentThread();

    public void run() {
        while(threadA == Thread.currentThread()){
            for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
                System.out.println("ThreadA " + i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopThread(){
        threadA = null;
    }
}
```

**Example Output:**

```
ThreadA 120
ThreadA 121
ThreadA 122
ThreadA 123
ThreadA 124
ThreadA 125
ThreadA 126
ThreadA 127
ThreadA 128
ThreadA 129
ThreadA 130
ThreadA 131
ThreadA 132
ThreadA 133
ThreadA 134
ThreadA 135
ThreadA 136
```

HOW TO KILL A THREAD

The class Thread has a method, stop(), that was supposed to know how to kill the current thread. But it was deprecated many years ago because it could bring some of the objects in your program into an inconsistent state caused by improper locking and unlocking of the object instances.

There are different approaches to killing threads. One of them involves creating your own method on the thread, say stopMe(), in which you set your own boolean variable, say stopMe, to false and test its value periodically inside the thread's method run(). If application code will set the value of stopMe to true, just exit the code execution in the method run(). In Listing 20-10, the loop in the method run checks the value of the variable stopMe, which is initialized with the reference to the current Thread object. As soon as it is changed (set to null in this case), the processing will complete.

The variable stopMe has been declared with a volatile keyword, which warns the Java compiler that another thread can modify it and that this variable shouldn't be cached in registers, so that all threads must always see its fresh value.

**Book Example Code on how to construct thread so that you can kill it if needed:**

```
 class KillTheThread{
               public static void main(String args[]){
               Portfolio4 p = new Portfolio4("Portfolio data");
             p.start();

             // Some other code goes here,
             // and now it's time to kill the thread
             p.stopMe();

               }
    }
class Portfolio4 extends Thread{

private volatile Thread stopMe = Thread.currentThread();

    public void stopMe() {
        stopMe = null;
    }

    public void run() {
        while (stopMe == Thread.currentThread()) {
          try{
            //Do some portfolio processing here
          }catch(InterruptedException e ){
            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                                        + e.toString());
        }

     }
 }
```

Comment: These classes are in different files, right?

Comment: Are you sure this code actually produced that output? It doesn't seem possible for this code to produce those values of `i`.

Comment: please provide the entire code, as this code doesn't makes sense compared to the output.

Comment: You have the exact code I'm running

Comment: Either this isn't the code you're running, or that's not the output you're getting.

Comment: this whole code makes no sense. The assignment of the threadA is done in the thread creating the instance so the while() would exit immediately.

Comment: I rebooted eclipse and now I don't get any output, but my question still remains, why doesn't the where condition return true, its always false.

Comment: see my answer above - add some syserrs and you'll see what I mean

Comment: I believe what you wanted was `while(threadA == this){`

Comment: I added the book's example code, maybe its bad code...

Comment: @Daft Punk no equally wrong - the problem is and stays that the thread object is created in the main-thread so threadA is the main-thread and in the run the new thread has started and current thread has a different value.

Comment: There was a craze for testing the current thread in some books in (I think) the late 1990s but I thought it had mercifully abated. Don't write junk code like this. The correct way to terminate a thread is to interrupt it and have it catch `InterruptedException` and break or return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `threadA` field is initialized by the main thread, before the `ThreadA` object becomes the current thread, so its value gets set to the main thread. When the loop runs, the `ThreadA` is the current thread, so no iterations occur. The weird output you were getting before you restarted Eclipse is likely due to Eclipse running a previous version of your code.

Comment: I added the book's description and its code.  What would be the proper way to accomplish their technique of killing the thread? I understand what you've explained above and I don't see any way a while condition could be used with the current setup of the classes.

Comment: @c12: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html

Comment: @c12:

public class ThreadA extends Thread{
    private volatile boolean run = true;

    public void run() {
     
        while(run){
            for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
                System.out.println("ThreadA " + i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void stopThread(){
        run = false;
    }
}

Answer (score 1):

1.
This will work only if ThreadA is the main thread.

2.
There is a much simple way of stopMe().

```
private volatile boolean stopped = false;
public void stopMe() {
    stopped = true;
}
public void run() {
    while (!stopped) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

3.
About "How to kill a thread". You can use `Thread.interrupt()`.
In fact, `FutureTask.cancel()` use `Thread.interrupt()` to stop working threads.

But, calling interrupt() actually is just sending a signal to a thread. The thread must do some extra work to response to the signal. It will not stop by itself.

It ends up you need to check `InterruptedException` and `Thread.isInterrupted()`, which basicly the same with `stopMe()`.